# Place a link within a infowindow using gmaps4rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, ruby-on-rails-3, dom-events, gmaps4rails

I am using gmaps4rails and now when I click on a marker appears information from the database, I need a putting a link inside the marker. How do I?

Model:

```
def gmaps4rails_address
  city
end

def gmaps4rails_infowindow
   "<h4>#{city}</h4>"  
end
```

Controller:

```
def index
  @postos = Posto.all
  @markers = Posto.all.to_gmaps4rails  

  @json = Posto.all.to_gmaps4rails  do |posto, marker|
    marker.json "\"id\": #{posto.id}"
  end  
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @postos }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't recommend you use the `gmaps4rails_infowindow` method: view details shouldn't be given at the model layer.

You should rather configure the infowindow in the controller, using a partial:

```
@json = Posto.all.to_gmaps4rails do |posto, marker|
  marker.infowindow render_to_string(:partial => "/path_to/your_template", :locals => { needed_locales })
end
```

Details are in the [gem's wiki](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Controller). (you could even use js templates but it's not the question and it's explained in the wiki as well)

Comment: please could tell me what would be my template?

Comment: It is probably the correct answer but I can not apply it effectively to solve the problem.

Comment: eu tenho este erro: Template is missing

Missing partial /postos/show.html with {:handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee], :formats=>[:html], :locale=>[:en, :en]}. Searched in: * "C:/Documents and Settings/bncosta/Desktop/trilho/app/views" * "C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/gmaps4rails-1.4.7/app/views"

Comment: a partial is always prepended by an underscore. This is very basic Rails btw.

Comment: But I need the infowindow has a direct link to the page show.html.erb

Comment: `marker.infowindow "<a href="/postos/show/#{posto.id}> Go to ... </a>"`

Answer (score 1):

Here are two ways.

Directly in the controller:

```
hashes = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(collection) do |item, marker|
  marker.infowindow(ActionController::Base.helpers.link_to(item.name ||= 'Name?',preplan_path(item)).html_safe)

  marker.title item.name
  marker.picture({
                     # :url => "/assets/building_icon.png",
                     :url => "/assets/text.png",
                     :width => 32,
                     :height => 32
                 })
  marker.lat item.latitude
  marker.lng item.longitude
end
```

And using a partial from the controller:

```
hashes = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(collection) do |item, marker|
  marker.infowindow render_to_string(:partial => "/structures/info_window", :locals => { :structure => item})
```

And the partial can be whatever you like:

```
# view/structures/_info_window.html.haml
= link_to structure.name, [structure.preplan, structure]
- unless structure.longitude.nil?
  %br
  = link_to "Drive to?", "https://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=#{structure.latitude},#{structure.longitude}", target: "_blank"
```

Comment: I asked this question four years ago when I was still studying rails 2. But anyway, thank you.